# Connecting to Azure SQL DB through PowerShell results in existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

Connecting to Azure SQL DB (PaaS) through Powershell

```
$sqlServer = "x.database.windows.net"
$sqlDB = "master"
$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$($sqlServer),1433;Initial Catalog=$($sqlDB);Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
$conn.AccessToken = $env:ACCESSTOKEN
$conn.Open()
```

I am then presented with the error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an 
error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed 
by the remote host.)"
At C:\Users\x\testcon2.ps1:6 char:1
+ $conn.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

- I am able to connect to server directly through SSMS with no issues.
- Firewall rule is in place.
- Minimum TLS 1.2
- Resource utilisation is zero
- There are no other connections to the DB apart from mine.
- I've looked through RingBuffer and eventlog in SQL side and can't see any errors.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Is your `AccessToken` getting set correctly and not expired? Try manually setting it wrong to see if you get e better error. Also, I recommend using the `Az.Sql` cmdlets when possible - they tend to handle az errors better.

Answer (score 0):

We need to install the module by running the command Install-Module Az

Try to authenticate to Azure by running

> Connect-AzAccount

We can find the database by running below command, if that returns the database you wanted to connect to, you are ready to run the script.

> Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName .

Below PS script will establish the connection and execute the query and give us the output.

```
Import-Module Az.Sql -Force
 
$rgName = '<Resource Group Name>'
$sqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$sqlDatabase = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $sqlServer.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
 
$Params = @{
   'ServerInstance' = $sqlServer.FullyQualifiedDomainName;
   'Database' = $sqlDatabase.DatabaseName[0];
   'Username' = $sqlServer.SqlAdministratorLogin;
   'Password' = ‘<Password>’;
   'Query' = 'SQL Statement to access table'
}
 
Invoke-Sqlcmd @Params
```

Also refer to [Microsoft article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-database-token-based-authentication-with-powershell/ba-p/369078) about Azure SQL Database Authentication with Powershell.

This connection issues usually occurs with the [service in few locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/32697/error-when-connecting-to-azure-sql-database-from-c.html), also when AccessToken expires.